# Помогите переписать с c++ на с абстрактный и наследуемые классы

Tags: c++, c

Помогите переписать часть кода с c++ на си. 
Есть абстрактный класс

```
class Shape
   {
    public:
    virtual void Draw() = 0;
    virtual int  GetArea() = 0;
     protected:
     int Tmk(int h);
     int  x;
     int y;           
   }
```

и 2 наследуемых класса

```
class Rectangle: public Shape
    { 
    public: 
       void Draw()
     {
    cout << "Rectangle" <<  endl;
  }
    private:
    int k;
   }

class Circle: public Shape

    {
    public:
    int GetArea()
    {
      return 6;
    }
    private:
    int z;
    };
```

В функции создаются объекты данных классов следующим образом:

```
Shape* shape;
if(...)
{
   shape = new Rectangle();
}
else if(...)
{
   shape = new Circle();
}
```

Как переписать данный код на С, чтобы потом была возможность из объекта класса `shape` получить доступ к методам и членам разных классов, например,

```
    ((shape*)figure)->Draw();
```

и выводилось "Rectangle"?

Comment: если у вас есть указатель, то по этому указателью вызовите метод. Причем тут вообше какие то преобразования и причем тут язык С?

Comment: В задании требуется переписать код с С++ на С. Попался такой фрагмент кода, который не знаю как переписать.

Comment: наверное просто нужно выделять память через `malloc`  вместо new

Comment: А от классов как избавиться? Мне требуется уйти от классов и методов, одновременно с этим сохранив логику работы программы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что-то в таком духе

```
typedef void (*Draw)(void *);

enum shape_type {
  RECTANGLE, CIRCLE, TRIANGLE
};

struct Shape {
  enum shape_type type; // на пракике я бы добавил ...
  Draw draw;

  int x, y;
};

struct Rectangle {
  struct Shape base;
  int k;
};

void draw_rect (void *p)
{
  printf("Rectangle %d\n", ((struct Rectangle *)p)->k);
}

void *Rectangle (int k)
{
  struct Rectangle *p = calloc(sizeof(*p), 1);
  p->base.type == RECTANGLE;
  p->base.draw = draw_rect;
  p->k = k;

  return p;
}


int
main(int ac, char *av[])
{
  struct Shape *shape = Rectangle(10);

  shape->draw(shape);

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Для Circle и других фигур аналогично.

Private, protected (и проч.), естественно, не моделируем.

Существенное упрощение, вызывающее лишний расход памяти, это  указатели на функции "класса наследника" **в каждом экземпляре** фигуры.

*В принципе, их (указатели на фукции) можно было бы бы хранить в отдельной статической структуре (одной на каждый тип фигуры), но 1) синтаксис `p->f()`  тут уже не реализуешь... 2) много будет возни с макросами (скорее всего оно того просто на стоит ... -)).*

Comment: добавлю, что `shape_type` в сущности не нужен, а указатели на функции хранить в отдельной статической структуре в сущности хорошая идея... да и ни какой возни с макросами они не добавляют... а ещё основная идея в том, что «базовый класс» __обязательно__ должен быть в самом начале структуры «наследника»

Comment: @Fat-Zer,  предлагаете выяснять тип фигуры по адресу конкретной draw()? Это накладывет ограничения на возможность ее динамического изменения

Comment: предлагаю в принципе не закладывать возможность выяснения типа фигуры, пока оно не понадобится...

Comment: поправлюсь: s/в сущности не нужен/вообще говоря, не обязателен/

Comment: @Fat-Zer, если набор встроенных в сущность функций исчерпывающий и неожиданных изменений задачи не будет,  вы правы, тип не нужен. А также, если вы по ходу обработки всегда на стадии компиляции знаете тип, то и все телодвижения с "наследованием" не нужны, вы в любой точке статически знаете, какие функции использовать с данным указателем. Но это так, общие рассуждения, наверняка не имеющие отношения к вопросу ТС